# How can I serialize Exceptions using Json.NET on WinRT?

Tags: windows-runtime, json.net

This works fine on classic .NET:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Exception("Test"));
```

But it fails on WinRT (RP) with:

`Error getting value from 'TargetSite' on 'System.Exception'.

The API 'System.Exception.get_TargetSite()' cannot be used on the current platform. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248273 for more information.`

EDIT: 
I also need to transfer the Exception over the wire and deserialize it on the back end side.

Anyone has any workarounds?

Comment: How about mapping the exception to a dictionary of fields that can be used on the platform and serialize the dictionary?  That should be fine as long as you don't need to deserialize back to an exception.

Comment: @JeffMercado That's the ting. I need to deserialize it back to an Exception later in the chain.

Comment: Well Exceptions in WinRT are just thin wrappers around the HRESULT returned from the API. If you just need the message and callstack you count create your own Exception that deserilises from json and that you then trow. But you can not expose this Exception type as a public class in WinRT.